# How to make PTSans bold style to look good in lower size than 16.5px?

Tags: css

I'm using a PTSans Webfont Kit from *ontsquirrel.com. ( *ontsquirrel.com/fonts/pt-sans )

I have setup a correct CSS code by using a dedicated font weight and style for bold, italic etc.

**The problem is that PTsans font variant bold need to have at least 16.5px in size to look good.**

That is creating a problem as the body text is set to 15px.

If I compare to Arial, bolded it looks good even in 12px size.

Can someone shed some light on this, or even better, recommend a solution please?

**NOTE: This is NOT a faux bold problem.**

Cheers.

Comment: Looks fine to me in 15px font: http://jsfiddle.net/rqxrbehe/2/

Comment: "16.5px" - Always wondered by **half a pixel** looked like. :)

Comment: @APAD1 - Yes, I see that your example works good even down to 12px! I'm going to try to pull this font from Google as you did. Will inform you about the result.

Comment: Sounds good, I will add that as an answer in case it resolves your issue ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PT Sans is a font that is available in the [Google Fonts library](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/PT+Sans). You might consider using Google's version of the webfont as their fonts are typically more reliable than those provided by the service you're currently using.

Here are a few different ways of implementing it from Google:

**Standard (this would go in the `head` of your HTML):**

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

**@import (this would go in the top of your CSS file):**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic);
```

**Javascript (this could be included directly in the HTML or in a separate JS file that you've included in the HTML):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'PT+Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic:latin' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(); </script>
```

Comment: That's the code you would use if you were hosting the font files yourself. You can get rid of that altogether now. All you need to do is implement one of the 3 options above and then you can apply `font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;` to any of the elements that you want to use that font.

Comment: I did that, and guess what - the problem is still present. I think that is something wicked in the WP design made by template designer. The solution is to get a new, fresh designed template. At least I know what i shall keep an eye on next time... Thanks.

Comment: Did you change the CSS to `font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;`? (notice the space between `PT` and `Sans`. If you left it without the space and left the code you posted above then it is still using the kit you got from Font Squirrel.

Comment: "Did you change the CSS to font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;?" That did the trick, thanks again!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Just a question though, as I need narrow bold variant as-well, PT Sans Narrow. Shall I create a separate import line, or is it possible to embed it in the original CSS link?

Comment: Yes, you will need an additional `@import` line: `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700);` The CSS for that font would look like this: `font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;`

Answer (score 0):

Fonts are rendered differently in browsers compared to Photoshop, I've come across this before with custom fonts. You'll need to change the font or change the design to make space for larger font. Are you a designer or has a designer given this to you? If so go back to them and explain that the design will need to change.

You can try using the anti-aliasing property, this doesn't work with every font but it's worth trying first.

```
   p{
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }
```

Another option is text shadow

```
   p{
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.01) 0 0 1px;
    }
```

If neither of these smooth the font then you will need to change the design

Comment: Will try this, although I've done that before if I remember well.

Comment: So it looks good at 16.5px and you wanted to be 15px? surely that's not too much of an increase in font size, wouldn't the simplest solution just be to increase your font-size to 16.5px?

Comment: Well yes, that may be a solution, but that breaks the template design concept. Very annoying and unnecessary problem.